# Unable to access griddb via terminal while its installed on ubuntu

Tags: griddb

I have installed GridDB on my Ubuntu machine by following the official installation guide. However, I am unable to access it via the terminal. When I try to run **`griddb`** command in the terminal, it throws an error saying "command not found".

I have checked the installation path and it seems like the **`griddb`** binary is located at **`/var/lib/gridstore/bin/griddb`**. I have also added this path to my system's **`$PATH`** variable, but still no luck.

What am I missing here? How can I access GridDB via terminal?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SpBr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0urHE.png)